# Observable to BehaviorSubject Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, behaviorsubject, rxdart

I'm new to rx so it is possible that I might be doing something terribly wrong.

I'm trying to convert an observable to a BehaviorSubject since I'd like to have:
- multiple observers
- initial value

```
Observable<Note> _observableResult;
BehaviorSubject<Note> result;

 Observable<FileSystemEntity> getContentOfDirectory(file) {
final dir = Directory(file);
try {
  var stream = dir
      .list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)
      .where((fse) => !fse.path.contains("DS_Store"));
  return Observable(stream);
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint('getNoteError: $e');
  // If encountering an error, return 0
  return Observable.just(null);
}
}


getNotes() async {
final file = await _localPath;//Future<String>

_observableResult = getContentOfDirectory(file)
    .asyncMap((fse) {
      if (fse is File) {
        return fse.readAsString();
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    })
    .where((e) => e != null)
    .asyncMap((s) => Note.fromJsonResponse(s));

result =
    BehaviorSubject().withLatestFrom(_observableResult, (one, two) => two);
  }
```

Error:
Observable is not a subtype of type BehaviorSubject

Obviously combineLatest is not right(?), but I did not find any decent way to convert between them...

Comment: A BehaviorSubject is a particular kind of observable, is there any reason why `getContentOfDirectory` is not of that type ? Also, your function uses try catch, you could just handle the error using the RxDart API.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to convert a Stream to a BehaviorSubject honestly, that's the only reason. Thanks for the try catch, will convert it.